# Insert output of bash command as a first line of a existing file?

Tags: bash, sed, tabs, insert

I have a list files in directory. I want put all list of files in first line of existing file separated by tab ("\t") value.

```
      #! /bin/bash
      me=$(ls *_vs_all.txt | sort)
      echo $me
      sed -ie "1i$me" aa.txt
```

but it's throwing error ...!

```
      sed: -e expression #1
```

How can I parse the output to first line file with tab value?

For example:

```
   o/p:
   a_vs_all.txt
   b_vs_all.txt
   c_vs_all.txt
   d_vs_all.txt
   e_vs_all.txt
   f_vs_all.txt
```

Append to the file

```
       a_vs_all.txt b_vs_all.txt    c_vs_all.txt    d_vs_all.txt    e_vs_all.txt    f_vs_all.txt
```

Comment: `ls | tr "\n" "\t"` is that what you want?

Comment: @  qqibrow .. yes ... your are absolutely right.

Comment: cool. I am a little confused by your title. anyway, I summarize an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls | tr "\n" "\t"` will output `ls` result to a single line separated by tab.

if you want to add this line to the head of existing file, check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/246837/how-do-i-add-text-to-the-beginning-of-a-file-in-bash)

Comment: yes you are also right .. but I failed to parse the output a file using 'ls' command and  'tr' worked for me.